# Box API search with special characters not returning correct results

Tags: box-api

I am doing search with following sequence "`!@#$`".
I have files with following file names:

```
$

    %#@,.;'.][}{.doc
    %&!@#$^$()-_+=;',.`~..doc
    .,!23!$0()-+=-_.doc
    -90[];'.doc
```

I am expecting  `%&!@#$^$()-_+=;',.`~..doc` file in my results but I don't see it. Even Box Net home doesn't show correct results

Can you explain the reason and solution for this issue?

Answer (score 0):

To resolve this, you need to put the full file name in quotes. Your search term should look like this:

```
"%#@,.;'.][}{.doc"
```

Quotes will allow the Box search engine to search for exact matches, especially when there are special characters involved. I also just tested and verified that this search term will work in the Box web application.